# Difference between these two declarations of dynamic arrays of objects of type test?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Why does the pointer `ptr` allows us to access its member function through
the dot operator `.` while `pt` doesn't as it requires the indirection operator `->`?

```
int n = 5;
test* ptr = new test[n];
ptr[1].print();
test* pt[45];
pt[1] = new test(2,3);
pt[1]->print();
```

Comment: Looks like you are using VLAs, which ain't standard c++.

Comment: @songyuanyao You are right, my bad, I was too quick. That's what you have with archaic code :(

Answer (score 1):

Because they're different things.

`ptr` is a pointer of type `test*`, it points to the 1st element of the array `test[n]`, whose elements are of type `test`, then `ptr[1]` gives the 2nd element with type `test`.

`pt` is an array, whose elements are of type `test*`, then `pt[1]` gives the 2nd element with type `test*`.

Answer (score 0):

because `ptr` is an array and `ptr[1]` alreadey derefrenced the pointer. While `pt` is array of pointers you need to derefrence twice.